# How to upload files using vuejs express and axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, axios

i want to upload files from my front and get them to my server side saved as simple path or something in my db (postgresql) . heres's my front :

```
<template>
<div class="mt-5 pt-2">
<div class="card" :class="$style.container">
  <div class="text-dark font-size-32 mb-3">Créer un compte</div>

       <a-form
        
        :model="registerForm"
        :rules="rules"
        layout="vertical"
        class="mb-4"
        @finish="handleFinish"
        @finishFailed="handleFinishFailed"
        @submit.prevent="handleSubmit"
      >
       
          <a-form-item name="act" label="Actone"  @change="uploadFile">
            <upload></upload>
          </a-form-item>
     
  
          <a-button
            type="primary"
            :loading="loading"
            @click.prevent="prev()"
            class="text-center w-50"
            ><strong>Previous</strong></a-button
          >
          <a-button
            type="primary"
            :loading="loading"
            html-type="submit"
            class="text-center w-50"
          >
            <strong>Confirm</strong>
          </a-button>
        </div>
      </a-form>
    
  </div>
 
         </div>

 </div>
   </template>
     <script>
   import { computed, reactive,toRaw } from "vue";
     import { useStore } from "vuex";
     import upload from "@/components/upload";
   import axios from "axios";
    export default {
    name: "VbLogin",
       components: {
          upload,
         },



const handleFinish = values => {
 console.log("registerForm")
  console.log(toRaw(registerForm))
  store.dispatch('user/REGISTER', { payload: toRaw(registerForm) })
};
const handleFinishFailed = (errors) => {
  console.log(errors);
};

return {
  
  registerForm,
  handleFinish,
  handleFinishFailed,
  };
},
     data() {
          return {
 
         files: null,
         };
       },
     methods: {
       prev() {
         this.step--;
         },
           next() {
         this.step++;
          },
        handleSubmit() {
         const formData = new FormData();

       formData.append("files", this.files);

          axios.post("/file-upload", formData, {}).then((res) => {
         console.log(res);
         });
          },
         uploadFile (event) {
              this.files = event.target.files
              },
         },

     };
     </script>
```

here's my back:

```
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'Uploads')
           },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, file.fieldname)
     }
     })

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

  router.post('/file-upload', upload.single('files'), (req, res, next) => {
const file = req.file
if (!file) {
  const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
  return next(error)
}
  res.send(file)

 })
```

Any help would be appreciated. now what's happenning is the message please upload file even tho i have uploaded it , (i want to upload 2 different files to 2 different inputs but i just want to  focus on one right now)

Comment: As a first step, you should check if the file is being sent to the back-end. Using DevTools, inspect the POST request that goes to the server - is the file there, encoded as `multipart/form-data`? This way, you'll know if the issue is on the server or on the client. Go from there. Use a simple test file (like a text file with "hello, world" inside) to make inspecting the request easier.

Comment: i have postman i tested with it the post method it works fine i get the filename,orgin,encoding etc.. returned

Comment: that means it's something on the client. Take a look in DevTools, see what ends up in the request data. Unfortunately, I don't know what <upload> is and am not a Vue expert, so not much I can do here.

Comment: i can share if you the code of upload but thanks anyway i understand